Intermittent failure to save categories/products
When we make changes to a product or category magento will get stuck on the "please wait" screen. There's no error and the changes do not save. So far, the issue is only when changing things in the "content" sections. Also, it doesn't happen all of the time but it is happening more often than it used to. Changing browsers or clearing cache doesn't seem to work.

To investigate this intermittent issue with saving categories and products, reviewing the logs is essential. Since the error isn’t visible on the frontend, the problem may stem from a background service or an issue in the database.

Magento Logs:

If your store is in developer mode, check debug.log in var/log/, as this will capture detailed debugging information not found in exception.log.
Additionally, review system.log for any possible module conflicts or errors related to custom code affecting product or category saves.


Web Server Logs:

If you’re using Apache or Nginx, review their error logs to check for timeouts or other interruptions:

Apache: /var/log/apache2/error.log
Nginx: /var/log/nginx/error.log


Caching layers like Redis or Varnish can also interfere with data saves if they’re misconfigured, so be sure to review:

Redis: /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
Varnish: /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log




PHP Logs:

PHP errors can sometimes lead to freeze behavior. Check the PHP error log (e.g., /var/log/php-fpm/error.log) for memory or timeout errors that may indicate the need to adjust PHP configurations.



If you’re managing a large Magento setup with complex configurations, feel free to reach out for a deeper review of your environment. A professional review can quickly pinpoint whether the issue is related to server limits, corrupted data, or custom module interactions.
Service Limits:

It’s possible that the issue is related to reaching certain limits in your server’s configuration. For instance:

max_input_vars: Limits the number of input variables your server can process, which might affect large data saves.
memory_limit: If the save process exceeds the allowed memory, it can cause timeouts or freeze behavior.
post_max_size and upload_max_filesize: If you’re uploading large files (e.g., in the content section), these limits might interfere.


Check your PHP and server settings to ensure these limits are adequately set for your store’s needs.

Database Integrity:

Sometimes, freezes during saves can be caused by database integrity issues, such as corrupted or duplicate entries. If Magento tries to save data that doesn’t meet database constraints, it may fail silently or get stuck. Running a database integrity check or inspecting the affected tables could help.

